# What can we conclude from the equality $m_A(x) = m_B(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Suppose $A,B \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ and $m_A(x) = m_B(x)$.

Is one of the following propositions is true?

(1) $f_A(x) = f_B(x)$

(2) A is invertible if and only if B is invertible.

I think that both of the propositions above are true but I didn't manage to prove them.

In case the propositions are correct can anyone give me an hint on how to prove them?

Otherwise, please provide a counter-example.

**Note** : $f_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $m_A(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: I was trying to figure out what can I conclude from the equality $m_A(x)= m_B(x)$. I showed two propositions which I believed were correct but couldn't prove them. I found out, Thanks to @Ehsan M.Kermani that my thoughts were wrong. I didn't have any solution process to show because I really didn't have any idea how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hints*:

1) Take $A=\text{diag}(1,1,2), B = \text{diag}(1,2,2).$

2) Eigenvalues of a matrix are roots of its characteristic polynomial as well as its minimal polynomial i.e. minimal and characteristic polynomial only differ by *multiplicities* of their roots.

Comment: First of all, Thank you very much. Regarding (2) - Do you mean that if 0 isn't eigenvalue of A (i.e. not a root of its minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$) then 0 isn't eigenvalue of B(i.e. not a root of its minimal polynomial $m_B(x)$) ?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB, you're welcome! yes, that'd imply what you said.

Comment: Thanks again :) You really helped me!

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB No worries :) see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29) as well.